# How to distinguish between personal site and OneDrive site types

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom

I use the

```
public virtual SPOSitePropertiesEnumerable GetSitePropertiesFromSharePointByFilters(SPOSitePropertiesEnumerableFilter speFilter);
```

function to retrieve SharePointOnline sites:

```
    do
{
    sitesEnumerable = tenant.GetSitePropertiesFromSharePointByFilters(new SPOSitePropertiesEnumerableFilter
    {
        IncludePersonalSite =  PersonalSiteFilter.Include ,
        IncludeDetail = false,
        StartIndex = nextIndex,
    });
    context.Load(sitesEnumerable, se => se.NextStartIndex,
                                  se => se.NextStartIndexFromSharePoint,
                                  se => se.Include(s => s.Url, s => s.Status, s => s.Template, s => s.Lcid,s => s.Title,s => s.HasHolds));
    context.ExecuteQuery();

    foreach (var site in sitesEnumerable)
    {
        //if site is OD site then 
        //  ProcessAsODSite()
        //else
        //  ProcessAsRegularSPOSite()
    }
}while (nextIndex != null);
```

In this way OneDrive sites are retrieved together with the regular sites with no special order.
I want to process the OneDrive sites differently then i process the OneDrive sites differently then i am processing the SPO regural sites.
**How can i distinguish between OneDrive sites and regular SPO sites for this matter?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the SitePrioerties.Template property to differentiate site types.
SPSPERS for one drive
STS for classic team sites
GROUP for modern team sites
SITEPAGEPUBLISHING for communication sites
etc

You can also prefilter to get just one kind of result with SPOSitePropertiesEnumerableFilter.Template